# Overriding Clojure spec in a different namespace

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I am wondering if there is a way from one namespace to change the spec in another namespace and still retain the uses of that modified spec in subsequent specs. The use case is that the namespace doing the overriding wants to make a var `nilable`.

As a simplified example, let's say that the core namespace has the following specs:

```
(ns ns-test.core
  (:require [clojure.spec.alpha :as s]))

(s/def ::string-spec string?)

(s/def ::string-vec (s/coll-of ::string-spec))
```

Then the override namespace wants to use the `::string-vec` spec but wants to make the individual elements nilable strings. When I implement it this way:

```
(ns ns-test.override
  (:require [clojure.spec.alpha :as s]
            [ns-test.core       :as c]))

(prn "1" (s/valid? ::c/string-vec ["s"]))
(prn "2" (s/valid? ::c/string-vec [nil]))

(in-ns 'ns-test.core)

(s/def ::string-spec (s/nilable string?))

(in-ns 'ns-test.override)

(prn "3" (s/valid? ::c/string-vec ["s"]))
(prn "4" (s/valid? ::c/string-spec nil))
(prn "5" (s/valid? ::c/string-vec [nil]))
```

It changes the `::c/string-spec` but not the `::c/string-vec`, and I do not want to copy all the dependent specs and redefine them as they are not changing from the definition other than the single var that is used in many other places.

```
"1" true                                                                                                                                                                                                    
"2" false                                                                                                                                                                                                
#namespace[ns-test.core]
:ns-test.core/string-spec
#namespace[ns-test.override]
"3" true                                                                                                                                                                        
"4" true                                                                                                                                                                                                 
"5" false
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior says nothing about namespaces
specs should not be changed at runtime.
In case you need to change at repl, you will need to reload/redefine all specs.